# Shaking Animation not working on API 19

Tags: android, animation

i use below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="70"
android:fromDegrees="-5"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="5" />


Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);    
itemView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Above code works fine on android 5.0 but not working properly on android 4.4 (API 19)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectAnimator`

```
ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView, "rotation", 0f, 20f, 0f, -20f, 0f);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    rotate.setDuration(100);
    rotate.start();
```

Comment: Nooo........i also gone through ObjectAnimator code, it also not worked for me. Check your code on android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

**ShakingAnimation :**

Set `android:repeatMode="reverse"` to achieve vibration effect. It also works pretty well on **API 19**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="100"
android:fromDegrees="-5"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:toDegrees="5" />
```